# Не получается запустить Spring boot приложение на разных портах

Tags: java, spring-boot, консоль, port, deploy

Необходимо запустить `Spring Boot` приложение на 3 разных портах **одновременно**.

Пользуюсь командой(с разными портами):

`java -Dserver.port=9091 -jar D:\IdeaProjects\Pet-projects\Coffeetearea\build\libs\Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

`java -Dserver.port=9092 -jar D:\IdeaProjects\Pet-projects\Coffeetearea\build\libs\Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

`java -Dserver.port=9093 -jar D:\IdeaProjects\Pet-projects\Coffeetearea\build\libs\Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

В консоли выдает ошибку:

`Error: Could not find or load main class .port=9091`

`Error: Could not find or load main class .port=9092`

`Error: Could not find or load main class .port=9093`

Не могу понять в чем может быть проблема. Во всех источниках пример следует через данную команду.
В `application.properties` добавлял `server.port=9091`, так же без него пробовал, итог один и тот же.

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/coffeetearea
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=*******
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
server.port=9091(Пробовал как с ним, так и без)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если задаете переменные через системные свойства, то пользуйтесь таким [синтаксисом](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding), а именно в имени переменной нужно заменить точки на подчеркивания и все буквы сделать заглавными:

```
java -DSERVER_PORT=9092 -jar D:\IdeaProjects\Pet-projects\Coffeetearea\build\libs\Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Альтернативный способ - это задать переменные через [параметры командной строки](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-command-line-args):

```
java -jar D:\IdeaProjects\Pet-projects\Coffeetearea\build\libs\Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=9092
```

Comment: 1) Не помогло. Пишет на остальных 2 стартах, что на порте 8081 по дефолту уже развернуто. Хотя я указываю 9090, 9091, 9092.


2)'Unrecognized option: --server.port=9092
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit'

Comment: Действительно, порядок неправильный указал. Сейчас исправил.

Comment: 2 вариант рабочий. Спасибо)